# Send message to topic - Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I want to send a message from my client app to other devices subscribed to a specific topic using Firebase.
Firebase docs telling me how to send this request in order to deploy this message:

Topic HTTP POST request
Send to a single topic:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send  
Content-Type:application/json  
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{  
  "to" : /topics/foo-bar",  
  "priority" : "high",  
  "notification" : {  
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",  
    "title" : "FCM Message",  
  }  
}
```

I don't know how to implement this in my code and I tried but with no success, Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = @{
                       @"body : "  : @"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message",
                       @"title : " : @"FCM Message"
                       };

NSDictionary *dic2 = @{
                      @"to : " : @"/topics/news",
                      @"priority : " : @"high",
                      @"notification : " : dic1

                      };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"key=MYKEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSError *error;
[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic1 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Hey did u get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.

The correct code is the following:

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = @{
                       @"body"  : @"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message",
                       @"title" : @"FCM Message"
                       };

NSDictionary *dic2 = @{
                       @"to" : @"/topics/news",
                       @"priority" : @"high",
                       @"notification" : dic1
                       };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"key=YOURKEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSError *error;
[request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic2 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]];
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request] resume];
```

I hope this will help anyone with this problem in the future.

Comment: Could you include some explanation of why/how the code is correct? That may help future people understand the problem better.

Comment: @mech You have to remove the double point behind the word "body" and behind the word "title"

Answer (score 0):

**Method for sending Notification on Topic**

```
class PushNotificationSender {


public static let shared = PushNotificationSender()
func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {
    let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : "/topics/Post",
                                       "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                       "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       request.setValue("key= set your server key find from your firbase cloud messging setting", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let jsonData = data {
                if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                }
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  PushNotificationSender.shared.sendPushNotification(to: "" , title: fullName , body: textView.text)
```